# Can the parameter in maximum likelihood function be infinty if that's when the maximum occurs?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I was working on this problem:

> Find the maximum likelihood estimator for the parameter $a$, in the distribution

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
3a^3\cdot x^{−4} & \text{if } x ≥ a \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The likelihood function came out to be $3a^{3n}\cdot X_1\cdot X_2\cdot X_3 \cdots X_n$, which, when differentiated wrt a and equating it to $0$, gives $3n/a = 0$, which is only satisfied if $a = +\infty$ or $n = 0$, both of which don't seem right to me.

Comment: Finding the maximum likelihood estimate is not always about differentiating the likelihood and setting it equal to zero.

Comment: yeah but even when i think about it normally I think it'll still be max at infinity since there's a product  x1.x2.x3..xn which is constant wrt a and a has a positive power.

Comment: Always consider the support of the distribution. The support is part of the density/likelihood. Your problem arises because of this oversight.

Comment: could you elaborate? i have a lot of difficulty understanding this topic in general

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2949033/321264 and its linked posts.

Comment: thanks i got it it now!